# How to integrate multiple Android Applications using the same Laravel Application using multiple FCM sender keys

Tags: firebase, laravel-5, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [brozot/laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/brozot/laravel-fcm) package for sending notification to users.

But I have multiple mobile apps (for each app I manage different server key and sender id) and I am using same laravel backend to send notifications to all different mobile apps.

How can I send notification to different app using different sender id (not using single sender id) with laravel brozot package?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the [brozot/Laravel-FCM](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) package documentation, ***specifying multiple Sender IDs doesn't seem to be a current feature***. You can see that only a single Sender ID is set in the `.env` file when [Setting the Package Config](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM#package-configuration), which I presume is the Sender ID automatically used for when the message is built.

The only way I can see this moving forward is for you to [file for a Feature Request](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM/issues).